# Saving web browser page through terminal

Tags: terminal, firefox, chrome, browser

Is there any way to use common web browsers such as firefox to fetch a page using command line interface? If I use `firefox www.google.com`, then firefox is opened and shows google page. I want to fetch the web site and save that a one or a bunch of files.

Comment: lynx, (e)links(2), w3m text browsers have a `-dump` option.  GUI browsers aren't much for supporting command-line...

Comment: Most people would use `wget` or `curl`, but the question is asking for a *web browser*.

Comment: Why do you insist on using Firefox, given that it may not be suitable for this task?

Comment: @jim-l: I want to analyze some time related things for fetching web pages. If chrome can do that, I will switch to that.

Answer (score 1):

you can download full webpage using `wget`:

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains website.com \
     --no-parent \
         www.website.com
```

The options are:

- `recursive`: download the entire Web site.
- `domains website.com`: don't follow links outside website.com.
- `no-parent`: don't follow links outside the directory `/`.
- `page-requisites`: get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on).
- `html-extension`: save files with the `.html` extension.
- `convert-links`: convert links so that they work locally, off-line.
- `restrict-file-names=windows`: modify filenames so that they will work in Windows as well (if needed).
- `no-clobber`: don't overwrite any existing files (used in case the download is interrupted and resumed).

Comment: No-clobber and convert-links no longer work together; convert-links will override no-clobber.